# Определение языка(русский, японский, испанский и т.д.) по текстовому файлу

Tags: php, python, linux

Есть текстовый файл. Надо, используя Linux или PHP или Python, определить на каком языке текс (английский, русский, китайский и т.д.).

Comment: Нужно считать частоту появления символов, биграмм и т.д. В зависимости от частот текст можно отнести к какому-либо языку. [Частоты для немецкого, английского.](https://github.com/tigertv/break-ciphers/tree/master/freq)

Comment: Частоты символов — хорошо, но недостаточно, я бы ещё брал корпус языка и пробовал морфемный разбор. Вот как отличить короткие фразы на удмуртском и монгольском?

Comment: А что имеется ввиду под фразой "используя Linux или PHP или Python"?

Comment: passant имею ввиду может есть готовое решение в php, python или linux.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Google Cloud Translation API

https://cloud.google.com/translate

[image: Google Cloud Translation API]